# Get the list of my projects in earthengine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm using the Google Earth Engine Python API. I want to get the full list of the asset that I can access from my account. I already have a method for that:

```py
def get_assets(folder=None, asset_list=[]):
    folder = folder if folder else ee.data.getAssetRoots()[0]["id"]

    for asset in ee.data.listAssets({"parent": folder})["assets"]:
        if asset["type"] == "FOLDER":
            asset_list += [asset]
            asset_list = get_assets(asset["name"], asset_list)
        else:
            asset_list += [asset]

    return asset_list
```

But to have the complete list I'm missing the names of the projects in "cloud assets".

Is there an easy way to get them as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this problem is actually not a pure earthengine problem but a cloud problem. Project are normal Google Cloud projects with a specific tags that will help us recognize them.

First you need to make sure that you have the correct libs installed in your env. add  `pip install google-cloud` (there were a lot of braking changes in version 1 it won't work with prior versions).

then authenticate in your terminal to add application credentials:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Now you can work in your python environment:

```py
from google.cloud.resourcemanager import ProjectsClient

for project in ProjectsClient().search_projects():
    if "earth-engine" in project.labels:
        print(project.project_id)
```

Using the function from the question I can now get the extensive list of everything I have access to from the code editor:

```py
from google.cloud.resourcemanager import ProjectsClient
import ee 

ee.Initialize()

# init with legacy assets
asset_list = get_assets()

# add assets from each project
for project in ProjectsClient().search_projects():
    if "earth-engine" in project.labels:
        asset_list += get_assets(folder=f"projects/{project.project_id}/assets")
        
asset_list
```